# Domain Name returning blank in Container Environment

Tags: c#, docker

We have a straightforward call to get the domain name for a check. See code below for a command line test app that was tried. In a non-container environment it works just fine. In our docker container environment it's returning blank.

```
var test = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;

Console.WriteLine(test);
```

We've tried various different methods to pull the domain name. Using different calls and tested with PowerShell commands as well. So far all methods that we could get working returned nothing. Our assumption there is some setup we're not doing correctly at this point. Otherwise quite stuck on this.

Comment: You can use `--domainname` with `docker run` to pass in the domain name to the container.

Comment: Tried something like this below but no change.

`docker run testdomain --domainname testdomain `

Comment: You have to put the argument before the image name, otherwise the argument just gets sent to the container that's created, instead of to docker.

Comment: Something like this? `docker run --domainname testdomain testdomain`
Same result, and thanks help.